# Difference in notation of conditional probability/expectation

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-expectation

Currently I am learning about conditional probabilities and expectations. In this question I focus on the expectation, but the question also holds for the probability notation and variance notation. I noted that there are two different methods to write down an expectation:

$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y))$ and $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y))$.

I am wondering if there is a difference between these notations.

Comment: The first is -as we know- $\mathbb E[X]$ by the tower property. By @AsbjornHolk's answer below the second expression is just $\varphi(y)$. Therefore $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y=y))$ is not really useful. In contrast to $\mathbb E[\varphi(Y)]$ which is again $\mathbb E[X]$ (no kidding) by the tower property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes there is a difference.
The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}]$ is in itself a random variable, while $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}=y]$ is just a real number.
Take for instance $\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}\sim N(\mathsf{Y}, \sigma^2)$.
Since the expectation of a normal random variable is its mean, we find that $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}]=\mathsf{Y}$, a random variable, while for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}=y]=y$ which is not a (non-degenerate) random variable.

In general, the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathcal{F}]$ of $\mathsf{X}$ given a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ is in itself a random variable satisfying certain criteria, namely being $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, integrable and integrating the same as $\mathsf{X}$ on $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\int_F\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathcal{F}]\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}=\int_F\mathsf{X}\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}$ for all $F\in\mathcal{F}$.
The conditional expectation given another random variable $\mathsf{Y}$ is implicitly the conditional expectation given $\sigma(\mathsf{Y})$, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra making $\mathsf{Y}$ measurable.
One can show that this amounts to saying that $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}]=\varphi(\mathsf{Y})$ for some measurable function $\varphi$, and you may then identify the quantity $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}\mid\mathsf{Y}=y]$ as $\varphi(y)$.

Comment: +1 Probably worth mentioning the [Doob-Dynkin lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%E2%80%93Dynkin_lemma#Statement_of_the_lemma) that gives us $\varphi(Y)$. The notation $\mathbb E[X|Y=y]$ is the source of much confusion because people wrongly think we condition on the event $\{Y=y\}$ which has probability zero when $Y$ is a continuous RV.